# Toyota Corolla 2002 Automatic - Flapping noise on hard acceleration

Tags: toyota, corolla

I've got a 2002 Toyota Corolla with an automatic transmission - 110k Miles.

When driving, if the revs get up to 3500 and above there is this loud flapping noise that gets louder and faster as the revs get higher.

This only happens in drive and does not happen when parked or in neutral - I've sat and revved the car up to see if the noise happens whilst parked and it doesn't

Comment: Could you elaborate "loud flapping noise"?

Comment: Could it be speed-related not acceleration?     Does the noise continue if revs drop and you cruise in top gear ?  (overdrive etc)

Comment: The noise disappears if in a higher gear but same speed (lower rpm)